# Cannot use json.dumps with the with python statement

Tags: python, json

When I run this code:

```
with open(f"{station_id}.json", "w+") as json_file_2:
    for hourly_json_raw in json_raw['hourly']['data']:
        hourly_json_raw['centroid_id'] = station_id
        hourly_json_raw['s3_key'] = s3_key
        json.dump(hourly_json_raw, json_file_2)
    json.dumps(json_file_2)
```

I have the error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'TextIOWrapper' is not JSON serializable.

It is because `json_file_2` has a format `io.TextIOWrapper`. However, I dont see how I can solve my problem:

1. Use an empty JSON file (the with line)
2. Append in the for loop this json_file iteratively
3. Finally dumps the final result.

Comment: `json.dumps()` converts a Python dict object to a string. You're converting it here, but discarding it without saving it.If you're trying to write to the file, that's `json_file_2.write(<string to write>)`

Comment: I think my problem comes from the fact that json_file_2 format is wrong

Comment: No, you can't use json.dumps() on a file. What are you intending that line to do

Comment: Why do you have both `json.dump()` and later `json.dumps()`? I would have thought you would only need one of the two: either you are writing multiple json strings to the file, or you write the whole of the updated `dict` (as json) to the file.

Comment: I first want to write several json strings to the file. Then, I want to have a format that I can upload in Amazon S3

Comment: Technically, if you write several json strings to a file, then that file is not in json format. Perhaps you could update the question with examples of what you expect to be in the file and what you want to send to S3.

Comment: This is not a problem. But Im pretty sure it should be feasible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant this:

```
with open(f"{station_id}.json", "w+") as json_file_2:
    for hourly_json_raw in json_raw['hourly']['data']:
        hourly_json_raw['centroid_id'] = station_id
        hourly_json_raw['s3_key'] = s3_key
        json.dump(hourly_json_raw, json_file_2)
with open(f"{station_id}.json", 'r') as f:
    json_for_S3 = f.read()

# Now write json_for_S3 to S3
```

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know tomorrow